# What does "a very heavily coded gay character" mean in the context of Ryuichi Sakamoto's Captain Yonoi and how was the coding implemented in the film?

Tags: japanese-cinema, merry-christmas-mr-lawrence

[image: screenshot from "The Truth Behind MERRY CHRISTMAS, MR. LAWRENCE (Expanded & Revised) | Cinema Nippon" https://youtu.be/aO3chPQOc_g]

I saw *Merry Christmas Mr. Lawrence* (1983) ([IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085933/)) in the theatre circa 1983 and did not at the time appreciate any of the context related to [Yukio Mishima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukio_Mishima) or homosexuality until I just watched the Cinema Nippon YouTube video [The Truth Behind MERRY CHRISTMAS, MR. LAWRENCE (Expanded & Revised) | Cinema Nippon](https://youtu.be/aO3chPQOc_g)

After about 05:00 one of the two narrators says:

> One of the main characters, Ryuichi Sakamoto's Captain Yonoi is the reason that I discovered this film in the first place years ago. He's a very heavily coded gay character who has some, shall we say, interesting scenes with Bowie's Celliers.

I don't know why but somehow I completely missed this when I saw the film. So I'd like to ask:

**Question:** What does the expression "a very heavily coded gay character" mean in the context of Ryuichi Sakamoto's Captain Yonoi, and how was the coding implemented in the film?

Comment: companion question: [What devices are this Japanese director(?) and his coworker looking through? If they are small format cameras, then why four right next to each other?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/119839/45856) & R.I.P. Ryuichi Sakamoto https://youtu.be/LGs_vGt0MY8 made me cry and I never knew why

Comment: in this context "heavily coded" means "having highly stereotypical traits of a gay man"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### He wasn't "very heavily coded"

He was clearly and obviously obsessed by Bowie's Celliers in a romantic way: he gives him special treatment, he watches him sleep, and he repeatedly asks after him. There's more coding in a teen sex comedy.